# Android BottomSheet Custom Animation speed

Tags: android, mobile, android-5.0-lollipop, bottom-sheet

Is there any way i could modify or set or override the exit animation duration of android bottomsheet component.

I tried `getDialog().getWindow().getExitTransition().setDuration(int);` but `getExitTransition()` throws NullPointerException.

Suggestions welcomed.

Comment: What class are you using? `BottomSheetDialog`?

Comment: i extended BottomSheetDialogFragment to implement my custom bottomsheet.

Comment: As I understand it, exit transitions can be undefined, in which case Android will simply perform the reverse of the enter transition. You may have to set an exit transition rather than try to modify one that apparently is not there.

Comment: Do you find a solution for this?